# get highest value in a given set in oracle/sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am new to oracle 11g, not sure the best way of doing this.  Thanks for any tips.

```
T1
id_set    id_
1         100 
1         101
1         102
1         103
2         100
2         101
2         102
2         108

T2
id_    tag    name
100    A       a
101    B1      b
102    B2      c
103    B3      d
108    B8      e
```

rules here is to check for a id_set, check if it contains tag = 'A' and tag =B*, select the one with highest integer after B.
so sample output will be:

```
id_set_    name    
1          d
2          e
```

i have up to B15, what is the best way of achieving this? thanks!
PS. tag number does not increase when id increases

Comment: [JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) with an [aggregate function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregate_function)

Comment: Your example output shows the value of the `name` column, yet you say you want the contents of the `tag` column. Which one is it?

Comment: sorry. edited. it is the name of highest tag number

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/12126/5)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (id_set, id_) AS
          SELECT 1, 100 FROM DUAL 
UNION ALL SELECT 1, 101 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1, 102 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1, 103 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 100 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 101 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 102 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 108 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE T2 (id_, tag, name) AS
          SELECT 100,    'A',       'a' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 101,    'B1',      'b' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 102,    'B2',      'c' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 103,    'B3',      'd' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 108,    'B8',      'e' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH max_tags AS (
  SELECT id_set, MAX( tag ) AS max_tag
  FROM   T1
         INNER JOIN
         T2
         ON (T1.id_ = T2.id_)
  GROUP  BY id_set
  HAVING MIN( tag ) = 'A'
  AND    MAX( tag ) LIKE 'B%'
)
SELECT id_set, name
FROM   max_tags m
       INNER JOIN
       T2 t
       ON (m.max_tag = t.tag)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/12126/5/0)**:

```
| ID_SET | NAME |
|--------|------|
|      1 |    d |
|      2 |    e |
```